# How to send Request Header to a Restful API

Tags: php, api, rest, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I am implementing a Restful API in PHP.

But how can I send GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests from the browser?

From where do I send the request header? Does that need to be send from some client application or can I test my API by sending headers manually? If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET is just a browser request, put the URL into the browser URL bar. You can send POST requests using a web browser if you write a HTML form. Write a HTML page with the fields to send to your API with a submit button. You can use something like Firebug to see the resulting header to debug.

If you want to send PUT or DELETE from a browser you need to use Javascript. The jQuery Javascript library has methods for sending requests from the browser to web APIs using AJAX.

If all you are looking for is a client to test your API then as jansel says you just use Postman in Chrome or HttpRequester in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer a tool to test your `Restfull` Web Services you can use [`Postman`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) Chrome extenssion.